# Toggle the like button in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I have an app to show products, I have a model class to convert data to Json

```
class TvShow {
  String id;
  String name;
  String image;
  String des;
  String date;
  List<Content> content;
  bool isLiked = false;

  TvShow({this.id,
    this.name,
    this.content,
    this.image,
    this.des,
    this.date,
    this.isLiked});

  void toggleIsLiked() {
    isLiked = !isLiked;
  }
```

all data came from Firebase database except (isLiked) I want to deal with it locally

I use provider package

```
List<TvShow> _favourites = [];
void addFavorite(TvShow tvShow) {
_favourites.add(tvShow);
notifyListeners();
}

 void removeFavorite(TvShow tvShow) {
_favourites.remove(tvShow);
notifyListeners();
  }

 void toggleLikeButton(TvShow tvShow) {
tvShow.toggleIsLiked();
notifyListeners();
 }

int get count {
return _favourites.length;
}

List<TvShow> get favoriteList {
return _favourites;
}
```

this is like button code

```
        Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              cardDataProvider.toggleLikeButton(tvShow);
              tvShow.isLiked == true
                  ? cardDataProvider.addFavorite(tvShow)
                  : cardDataProvider.removeFavorite(tvShow);
            },
            icon: tvShow.isLiked == true
                ? Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  )
                : Icon(
                    Icons.favorite_border,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
      ),
    ),
```

Then I display the favorite list in favorite screen

The problem is when I click on like button it turns into red heart for a little bit then it turns back to empty heart.

[image]

Is there a solution for that or a better way to do this idea, also I want to show like button state in another screen.

Thank you.

Comment: when you change something you have to use the setState{} method the change must be set inside the setState{}

Answer (score 0):

this should do it :
wrap your function with setState((){})
just like this :

```
setState((){


cardDataProvider.toggleLikeButton(tvShow);
          tvShow.isLiked == true
              ? cardDataProvider.addFavorite(tvShow)
              : cardDataProvider.removeFavorite(tvShow);
});
```